# Eclipse tooling for Blueprint XML

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, blueprint-osgi

Is there an Eclipse plug-in which specifically supports editing [Blueprint XML](http://aries.apache.org/modules/blueprint.html) files? E.g. autocomplete reference ids, interface names, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse's XML Editor helps with autocomplete of the Blueprint XML's tags along with help on available attributes for any tag. However, it cannot auto-complete interface names and reference Ids.